# Line-height is extending the a href range

Tags: html, css

As the title says:

```
<style type="text/css" scoped>
    @media(min-width: 640px){
        .<?php echo $championget;?>{
            background-image: url('<?php echo 'assets/champions/'.$championget;?>_pc.jpg');
            background-position: center center;
        }
    }
    @media(max-width: 639px){
        .<?php echo $championget; ?>{
            background-image: url('<?php echo 'assets/champions/'.$championget; ?>_mobile.jpg');
            background-position: center center;
        }
    }
</style>
<?php   echo '<a href="index.php?Champion='.$championget.'"><div class="';
    echo $championget;
    echo ' champion"><p id="champion_text">'.$championget.'</p></div></a>';
?>
```

And the `#champion_text` CSS that does it:

```
#champion_text{
    color:white;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 23px;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000,  
        1px -1px 0 #000,
        -1px 1px 0 #000,
        1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

Picture showing the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/meQ1C.jpg

Comment: That's the expected behaviour, as far as I know... What exactly were you trying to accomplish in there?

Comment: well I was just trying to move the text down and the whole button to be clickable

Comment: If you are trying to get the same area of your div clickable by href just try something like: 
[html] 
<a class="myHref">
    <div class="myTile"></div>
<a>
[css]
.myHref{height 10%; width: 80%: left: 10%; top: 0; position:fixed; }
.mymyTile{height 10%; width: 80%: left: 10%; top: 0; position:fixed;background-color:blue;}

Hope I got yoour question and my answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather use this approach to move it down. Remove the **line-height** and add my CSS **(in uppercase)**...

```
#champion_text{
color:white;
/*line-height: 60px;*/
DISPLAY: INLINE-BLOCK;
PADDING-TOP: 30px; /*You'll have to play width the amount... 30px is just my guess */
font-size: 23px;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000,  
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;
```

}

**OR** Push it down by relative position and (30px) from the top. See upper case CSS below.

```
#champion_text{
color:white;
/*line-height: 60px;*/
POSITION: RELATIVE;
TOP: 30px; /*You'll have to play width the amount... 30px is just my guess */
font-size: 23px;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000,  
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;
```

}

Comment: That worked thank you very much, could you explain to me what display: inline-block was used for in this scenario?

Comment: Sure... In a nutshell "block" elements such as the trusty old <div> will fill the whole width of the parent container. Where as inline elements - like <span> tags will not. They will "sit" next to each other on the page. 

Because I wasn't sure if you might at a later stage want some element on the far right I've decided to use inline-block. You'll now have an inline element but can apply the properties of a block element to it if needs be. Don't always use it by default. Here's a good article explaining it: http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/